# Unable to access docker-compose containers created inside docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that starts up a simple HTTP echo service on port `8800`.

```
version: '2'

services:
    echo-server:
        image: luisbebop/echo-server
        container_name: echo-server
        ports:
        - "8800:8800"
```

Super simple stuff. If I run `docker-compose up` and run on my local machine:

```
echo "Hello World" | nc 127.0.0.1 8800
```

Then I see the echo. **However:** If I run this same compose scenario inside a docker container, through the GitLab runner, it fails.

I've tried to garner attention for this issue at GitLab here, but with limited results: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/26566

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like:

```
---

stages:
  - docker_test

services:
  - docker:dind

docker_test:
  stage: docker_test
  image: docker:latest
  script:
  - docker version
  - apk update
  - apk add py-pip
  - pip install docker-compose
  - docker-compose up -d
  - sleep 10
  - netstat -tulpn
  - docker-compose port echo-server 8800
  - echo "Hello world" | nc 127.0.0.1 8800
```

And the output of `gitlab-ci-multi-runner exec docker --docker-privileged docker_test` is:

```
$ netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name

$ docker-compose port echo-server 8800
0.0.0.0:8800

$ echo "Hello world" | nc 127.0.0.1 8800
ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

So it seems like these ports aren't available inside the docker container, which is in charge of the docker-compose services. Am I doing something wrong?

I **do not** want the ports exposed at the host level, rather I just want the ports opened *by the docker container running the build*, available to that container.

```
Host (My Mac) -> GitLab CI Container -> Docker Compose Container exposing 8800

  ^ Not here        ^ I want port 8800 accessible here
```

**Edit:** Further, if I attach a shell to the running CI container, I see:

```
/ # docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
ab192edf5872        luisbebop/echo-server   "/opt/echo-server/..."   2 minutes ago       Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8800->8800/tcp   echo-server
/ # netstat -nltup
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
```

So it "sees" the container, and the port mappings look okay, but the port isn't actually listening.

Comment: This thing is that the "inside" docker still runs on the outside docker engine - so the port bind actually binds to the localhost of the "root" host machine. However you should be able to specify docker network to use in the docker-compose file and set it to what docker network is attached to the GitLab container. The  you will be able to connect to `nc echo-server 8800`

Comment: to my previous comment, most likely the GitLab container will use `bridge` network. Add `network_mode: bridge` to the `echo-server` in your docker-compose.yml. Then change the commands to `nc echo-server 8800`. It may still not resolve the domain name. In that case you can get the IP via `$( docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' echo-server )`

Comment: Hi @LukášDoležal, I'm not entirely sure that's the case. If I run `docker ps` at the "root" host machine, I see two containers - the `docker:dind` service, and the `docker:latest` image. If I run `docker ps` inside the `docker:dind` container, I see the three containers started by `docker-compose` - so the two sets of containers seem independent. Further, I cannot access the web service on `8800` from the "root" host (my Mac) even though I know it's running. (But I can if I just run `docker-compose` manually, as seen at the top of the question.)

Comment: did you check if nc command is present in the `docker:dind` or the `docker:latest` image? This error may be because of that. Normally nc doesn't come installed in images

Comment: @TarunLalwani The `nc` command does come pre-installed in `docker:latest`, which is where I'm running it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The container is running on the *"docker host"* which is, in your case, the other container that is supporting the Gitlab build:

```
services:
  - docker:dind
```

If I'm not wrong, its host name is `docker`. So access as this:

```
echo "Hello world" | nc docker 8800
```

To figure out what is the host of the docker daemon, use this:

```
script:
  - echo $DOCKER_HOST
```

Comment: That did it. You're 2 for 2 on my recent Docker questions. :-) Bounty in ~23 hours.

Comment: $ echo $DOCKER_HOST
tcp://docker:2375

Comment: Cool, but what to I have to do if I require to http-connect to the started docker (`docker run --detach -p 8000:8000`)?
`$DOCKER_HOST` is showing `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`. Connecting to `http://docker:8000` or `unix:///var/run/docker.sock:8000` fails. Everything runs under GitLab-CI.